# Art project idea: Possibly using Jquery or Flash

Tags: jquery, flash

Had for an photo art project using two images. The first image would be a black and white photo of some place where there is normally a lot of activity (a cafe, for example), this picture wouldn't have any people in it.  The second picture (color) would be taken from the very same angle/position except this one would have a lot more activity in it.

On a website, the black and white picture would be the default, but when a user moves their cursor over the photo, hints of the other photo begin to surface (most likely dense at the center and more diffused near the edges. A variable density effect would be cool too)

Is a project like this possible in Jquery (preferred because I know some Javascript), or would I have to use Flash? Any other ways to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think whatever you exactly want to do with images, pixels and colors, flash can be a solution. It has many colorfilters and possibilities to handle such a project.

On the other hand if you already know how to code javascript, flash won't be too hard as they are both *ECMAScripts*. If you don't want a heavy project, some basic knowledge will do it.

If you want to try the flash way, here is the reference to start with for Actionscript 3 (I think you could also use AS2, it also has colormatrix and bitmapdata and stuff):

[Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html#top).

Also, read the parts

[BitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html),

[ColorMatrix](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/motion/ColorMatrix.html)

and

[ColorMatrixFilter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/ColorMatrixFilter.html).

I'm not sure what jQuery can do, but for sure flash is capable of these image manipulations. Even on a pixel-level.

If you are fine to have embedded flash on your site. If you choose this way, and have more questions on how to start it, feel free to ask. I hope this gives some ideas to start with.

Comment: Thanks! I was hesitant to get into actionscript and flash but I guess that would be the easiest way.